# FeignClient service name configure through application.properties not working

Tags: spring-boot, feign

I am trying configure service name for FeignClient from application.properties.

It works when I hardcode my service name like below.

```
@FeignClient("userdetail-service")

public interface UserServiceClient {
@RequestMapping(
            method= RequestMethod.GET,
            value = "/alluser/getmyuser)
    String getUserDetails();
    }
```

But same thing does not work when I try through application.properties

```
@FeignClient("${userservice.name}")

public interface UserServiceClient {
@RequestMapping(
            method= RequestMethod.GET,
            value = "/alluser/getmyuser)
    String getUserDetails();
    }
```

and in my application.properties i added below

```
userservice.name="userdetail-service"
```

I get below error when I start spring application

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service id not legal hostname ("userdetail-service")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need quotes in your application.properties file. Try

```
userservice.name=userdetail-service
```